# Passing Ruby var as Javascript Parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass a ruby var as a javascript function param in a Rails checkbox, like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'Sugestão', prato.id , prato.sugestao,:class => prato.categoria_pratos_id, :id => "task-check3",:onchange =>"checkbox('<%=prato.categoria_pratos_id%>')"  %>
```

I have the Javascript checkbox Function working fine. But i need to pass the id as the param... It just gives me application error if i do that

Comment: u mean like an hidden field?

Comment: And by the way, you have erb interpolation in erb interpolation, while you just need `"checkbox('#{prato.categoria_pratos_id}')"`

Comment: works like a charm! Post the answer i'll accept :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have erb interpolation within erb interpolation, while you just need to interpolate ruby variable in a ruby string :

```
onchange: "checkbox('#{prato.categoria_pratos_id}')"
```

Comment: what if i want to send 2 parameters?

Answer (score 3):

It's because what you're giving within `<%= %>` is Ruby. You don't have to use the notation again while passing your parameter. Simply use `:onchange => "checkbox('#{your_id}')"`

Comment: what if i want to send 2 parameters?

Comment: `"checkbox('#{param1}', '#{param2}')"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use <%= %> within <%=%>. Instead, use #{} for the within. Like ...('#{prato.id}')...

Comment: how do i send 2 parameters?

Comment: The same: ('#{something}', '#{another}')